# How can I tell if my MacMini 2012 power supply is dead?

Tags: hardware, mac-mini, power, repair

I have a Mac Mini late-2012 A1347 that will not power on. I've tried the steps to reset the SMC (unplug-wait 30s-plug-wait 5s) and still nothing happens when I press the power button. No chime, no nothing.

How can I tell if it is something as simple as replacing the power supply with something like this:

https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/Mac-mini-A1347-Late-2012-Late-2014-Power-Supply/IF171-017?o=1

I'd rather not go to an Apple store or repair shop if I can avoid it.

Comment: Honestly without the right test equipment (like a multi-meter at a minimum) and the knowledge on how to *use* the test equipment to diagnose the issue, you can't. If you can return the power supply after installing it I would go ahead. Otherwise it is just an educated guess.

Comment: I’ve got a DMM...

Comment: Assuming you know exactly what to test and how (I don't) you may be on your way. But detailed electrical troubleshooting may be out of scope of AD and nearly impossible to do unless all you need is pointers to reference material.

Comment: The best way to narrow it down with minimal to no tools is to remove the ram and see if it will boot to an error chime. Suppose it does boot with an error chime.  You know factually, your mainboard, power supply, CPU, and video system are functioning.  It was either the likely the ram, or less likely the ram slots and definitely not the power supply. Also if all this occurs, if you reseat the ram it just may resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found this page:

https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/571061/Complete+Dead+-+How+To+Check+Power+Supply+Vs+Logic+Board

There was a correct DC voltage on each of the pins, so I believe the problem is elsewhere...